# Parameter on custom edit route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this code inside my show view:

```
<% if @user == current_user || is_admin? %>
    <%= link_to edit_user_path(@user), :class => "btn btn-default" do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Uredi informacije
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this custom route for editing user profiles:

```
get "/korisnik/:id/uredi" => "users#edit", as: "edit_user_path"
```

However, when I want to edit user informations it still redirects me to `/users/:id/edit`. I tried with `edit_user_path(:id)` or `edit_user_path(user)` but it doesn't work (shows me invalid route error). What parameter needs to come on this custom route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try modifying code in your routes.rb like this

```
get "/korisnik/:id/uredi" => "users#edit", as: :edit_user
```

no need to add _path at the end for alias or named routes. rails will automatically do it for you

Answer (score 0):

just remove 'as' part from your routes, put simple as

```
get "/korisnik/:id/uredi" => "users#edit"
```

and check your newly created routes with `bundle exec rake routes`